# ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I want to create 4 pdf files using iText. While running the code the first two of are successfully created. The remaning two throw an Exception "ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages."

Here is the code for pdf creation part:

```
public static Boolean createPDFFile(String filename, int headerType, List<DremelitemDetails> itemDetails) {
    try {
        path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath();
        column = 0;
        // create the pdf file
        props.load(new FileInputStream("Properties\\eng.properties"));
        COLUMNS = new float[][] {
                { MARGIN_LEFT, MARGIN_BOTTOM, (PageSize.LETTER.rotate().getWidth() - MARGIN_ENTER_COLUMNS) / 2,
                    PageSize.LETTER.rotate().getTop(MARGIN_TOP) },
                    { (PageSize.LETTER.rotate().getWidth() + MARGIN_ENTER_COLUMNS) / 2, MARGIN_BOTTOM,
                        PageSize.LETTER.rotate().getRight(MARGIN_RIGHT), PageSize.LETTER.rotate().getTop(MARGIN_TOP) } };
        String fontPath = "font\\arialuni.TTF";
        unicodeFont = BaseFont.createFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        mmPDFDocument = new Document(PageSize.LETTER.rotate(), MARGIN_LEFT, MARGIN_RIGHT, MARGIN_TOP, MARGIN_BOTTOM);
        pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(mmPDFDocument, new FileOutputStream(filename));
        mmPDFDocument.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.rotate());


        /*String[] footer = { props.getProperty("header"), "fdftfdbfbug",
                    "\u00a9" + props.getProperty("footer1"), props.getProperty("footer2")};*/
        String[] footer = { "SUMMARY OF PROJECTS", "Home Décor",
                "\u00a92011 Robert Bosch Tool Corporation. All Rigths Reserved.",
        "Web content and services - on demand, on your printer www.eprintcentre.com" };

        pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new HeaderFooter(mmPDFDocument.right() - mmPDFDocument.left(), footer, path, headerType, unicodeFont));

        mmPDFDocument.open();
        COLUMNS[0][3] = mmPDFDocument.top();
        COLUMNS[1][3] = mmPDFDocument.top();
        pdfColumn = new ColumnText(pdfWriter.getDirectContent());
        pdfColumn.setSimpleColumn(COLUMNS[column][0], COLUMNS[column][1], COLUMNS[column][2], COLUMNS[column][3]);
        pdfColumn.setSpaceCharRatio(PdfWriter.NO_SPACE_CHAR_RATIO);
        /* For generating Pdf */
        addItemDetails(itemDetails);
        mmPDFDocument.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException-------"+e);
        closePDFFile();
        return false;
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        System.out.println("DocumentException-------"+e);
        closePDFFile();
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception-------"+e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    DremelData dremelData = new DremelData();
    DremelPDFBulid dremelPDFBulid = new DremelPDFBulid();

    Document doc = dremelData.readXml("C:\\eng.xml");        
    ArrayList<DremelitemDetails> homeDeco = dremelData.parseNode(1, 11, doc); 
    ArrayList<DremelitemDetails> artsAndCrafts = dremelData.parseNode(12, 24, doc); 
    ArrayList<DremelitemDetails> seasonalIdeas = dremelData.parseNode(25, 36, doc); 
    ArrayList<DremelitemDetails> DIYRestoration = dremelData.parseNode(37, 49, doc);       

    try {

        dremelPDFBulid.createPDFFile("c:\\sam1.pdf", 0, homeDeco);
        dremelPDFBulid.createPDFFile("c:\\sam2.pdf", 1, artsAndCrafts);
        dremelPDFBulid.createPDFFile("c:\\sam3.pdf", 2, seasonalIdeas);
        dremelPDFBulid.createPDFFile("c:\\sam4.pdf", 3, DIYRestoration);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in readXml : " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

In the above code the content of sam3 and samp4 pdf's are empty and showing "The document has no pages." exception

Comment: Does the ArrayList contain entries for the 3th and 4th call?